# How can I notify Google that my content is human-written, not AI?

Tags: google, content, technical-seo, education, issue-trackers

I am in a dilemma as I have written many articles myself. I didn't get any help from any AI content generator tool. When I check my content using many AI Content Detector Tools, they all are showing different results. I don't know how to justify that content written by me is human-written. Because it's important for me to pass my article to rank in Google.

Now I want to know how to notify Google that my content is written by a human.

Kindly help me with that.

Comment: Do you have a website?  have you added a page with this content to it?  Is it indexed by Google?

Comment: Yes, in the last 10 days, I posted 10 articles, and 6 out of 10 got indexed automatically while for the remaining articles, I made the manual request in webmaster to index my blogs. All the blogs are well-written and have rich information.

My question is how can I notify Google that my Content is human-written?

Comment: There is, most likely, no way to tell Google you wrote the articles by hand, simply because that would get abused very quickly. I wouldn't fret too much over this, you have little power over how Google judges your articles anyway. Try to make you site easy and interesting for humans to visit, and Google will follow them.